# Fluent methods library for C#

Tags: c#, .net

Where can I find a library with collections of fluent methods as in Rails

I found some [here](http://fluentdatetime.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here
http://ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx

http://flimflan.com/blog/ReadableRegularExpressions.aspx

Comment: I hope I'm not the only one who finds those "ReadableRegularExpressions" notoriously unreadable.

Answer (score 2):

[CuttingEdge.Conditions](http://conditions.codeplex.com/) is another one.

Answer (score 1):

http://fluentnhibernate.org/

Answer (score 1):

My favorite; dependency intection: http://www.ninject.org